# Why doesn't navigation appear when I add an image?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am using Owl carousel. But when I use the img tag, nav and dots do not appear. Can you help me?

Here is html code;

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://anemurionhotel.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Blue-Abstract-Background-7-1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the image is too big. Can you try adding

```
img {   
 width: 100%;
}
```

to your CSS file and see if that works?